# How do I access a class object stored in an array?

Tags: arrays, lisp, common-lisp

So If I have a defclass object and I make an instance of it and place it inside an array. How do I get the value of its slots inside the array?

I've tried:

```
(slot-value (aref *array* 0) :name)
```

I guess I am just not understanding how to access an object that is inside an array.

I can print the object in an unreadable form using (format t) but is there a way to print an object and all the slots in a form I can actually understand?

```
(defun generate-object (name)
  (let ((a (make-instance 'person
                          :name name)))
    (setf (aref *array* 0) a)))
```

it places the object inside the array but it seems that the slot is not being created?

This causes the problem:

```
(defclass person ()
  ((name :accessor name
         :reader read-name
         :initarg :name)))

(defvar *array* 0)
(setf *array* (make-array 20))

(defun generate-object (name)
  (let ((a (make-instance 'person
                          :name name)))
    (setf (aref *array* 0) a)))
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I need to access the value of a slot inside an object that is inside an array. I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: I get an error that says: when attempting to ~A the slot ~S is missing from the object. but my function creates the class and sets the values of the slots correctly. I'll edit my function into my post.

Comment: Could you post a complete but minimal version of your code that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I updated the post with a minimal version.

Comment: Your slot specifier needs to look like this (name :accessor name :reader read-name :initarg :name)

Comment: I updated the code in my image and it still says that the slot is missing from the object. I used the debugger to check the value of the object and it says that it is at index 0 and it does have the name slot.

Comment: Try this instead (slot-value (a ref *array* 0) 'name)

Comment: Thank you it worked! , please post that as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The slot name needs to be a symbol that is [syntactically valid as a variable name](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defcla.htm).  Try `'name` instead of `:name` .

```
(slot-value (aref *array* 0) 'name)
```

Look at the examples [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_slt_va.htm).

Comment: That's the same *syntax* as the original:  slot-value object slot-name.  The important difference is that OP's object didn't have a slot named by the keyword symbol `:name`, but rather by some other symbol `name`.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I have fixed my sloppy wording.  Also, according to the standard, it looks like slot names cannot be keyword symbols.

Comment: +1 for updating.  The answer was definitely what was needed;  I was just nitpicking. :)  Investigating keyword use is always a good idea.  I've always liked that you can use non-keyword symbols as keyword-names for keyword arguments.  E.g., `(defun foo (&key ((bar baz))) baz)` and call `(foo 'bar 42)`.

Answer (score 0):

While possible, it is not recommended to use `slot-value` outside of the low-level class-specific code (like `initialize-instance` methods etc.).

You should instead add accessors to your slots and use those.  For example:

```
(defclass foo ()
  ((bar :reader foo-bar
        :initarg :bar)))
```

This defines a class `foo` with a slot `bar`.  You can initialize the slot upon object instantiation with the `:initarg` name:

```
(let ((my-foo (make-instance 'foo :bar "baz")))
  #| whatever |#)
```

You can read the slot value with the defined `:reader`:

```
(let ((my-foo (make-instance 'foo :bar "baz")))
  (foo-bar my-foo))
```

It doesn't matter where you get your `foo` from, of course.  Imagine you have an array `foo-array` which is filled with `foo`s.  To get the `bar` slot value of the fourth `foo` in that array:

```
(foo-bar (aref foo-array 3))
```

If you also want to set the value, use an `:accessor` instead of the `:reader` slot option.
Then you can use it as a *place*:

```
(let ((my-foo (make-instance 'foo)))
  (setf (foo-bar my-foo) "quux"))
```